# Runtime.exec() the executable library not work in non root

Tags: java, android, executable, runtime.exec

i have a code :

```
    private static String writeCommandToConsole(Process proc, String command, boolean ignoreError) throws Exception {
    byte[] tmpArray = new byte[1024];
    proc.getOutputStream().write((command + "\n").getBytes());
    proc.getOutputStream().flush();
    int bytesRead;
    if (proc.getErrorStream().available() > 0) {
        if ((bytesRead = proc.getErrorStream().read(tmpArray)) > 1) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, new String(tmpArray, 0, bytesRead));
            if (!ignoreError)
                throw new Exception(new String(tmpArray, 0, bytesRead));
        }
    }
    if (proc.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
        bytesRead = proc.getInputStream().read(tmpArray);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, new String(tmpArray, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    return new String(tmpArray);
}

public static void Changes(Context con, int fNums, String fNames, int is, boolean bools, String strs) {
    final String fNum = String.valueOf(fNums);
    final String fName = fNames;
    final String i = String.valueOf(is);
    final String str = strs;
    final String bool = bools ? "true" : "false";
    final String path = pathExecutable + " " + fNum + " \"" + fName + "\" " + i + " " + bool + " \"" + str + "\"";
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (isRoot) {
                        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su"});
                        writeCommandToConsole(proc, path, true);
                    } else {
                        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
                        proc.wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
}
```

for root is work well (my phone is rooted) .. but for non root it not work (use parallel space, virtualXposed,etc in non root phone) .. in non root only work in virtual machine which have a root (vmos,x8 sabdbox etc).

i was try use processBuilder but have a same result .. executable lib seem not get into the target ..

how to write a correct runtime.exec to make it work on non root phone (use parallel space or any cloner without virtual machine with root include) ? or is it any way to make it posible to run executable lib without su command ?

Comment: Can you be more precise than "not work"? What do you mean by "executable lib"? What binary are you trying to launch?

Comment: i try to patching the game hex memory .. in root phone it run well the hex patching is work perfectly .. but when i try in non root the patch not success ..

Comment: Are you trying to patch the memory of the *current* application or of another application? If it's the later then that's by design: your app can't touch any other applications memory. That would be a huge security problem (as is root).

Comment: patching another aplication .. just need to know why it can be patched in non root use a virtual app (parallel space etc).. is my runtime.exec command wrong or what ? i was try gameguardian .. that app need root but can run well in non root use virtual.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but can run well in non root use virtual". I might be lacking some knowledge here, but I know that patching arbitrary unrelated apps like this is **definitely** forbidden and prevented in standard Android. I don't know about these "virtual apps" you talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved .. i change non root command into

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh"});
writeCommandToConsole(proc, path, true);

and it run well in some virtual app ..